# I have seen people define frequency or amplitude in two ways, which one is correct?

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency, wavelength, intensity

I have a doubt on frequency and amplitude,I have seen people define these things in 2 ways,for instance, people define frequency in mainly 2 ways,[image]if we draw a pressure-position graph of a sound wave,then it's frequency would be the number of compression or rarefaction passing through a point within a second,and,amplitude will be how much high pressure or low pressure is created[image]if we focus on a individual air molecule,And draw it's displacement-time or Displacement-distance graph,then the frequency should be how many times it vibrates or oscillates in a second,and the amplitude should tell the displacement of how far it goes when vibrating or oscillating,right?So,how do I know at what instance about what graph is a person talking?are these graphs incorrect?if yes,then what is frequency or amplitude,if not,then tell me one thing,we say that loudness or pitch of a sound is determined by its amplitude or frequency,so,here,what frequency or amplitude are we talking about? frequency or amplitude of the pressure-position graph,that is, frequency or amplitude of compression or rarefaction travelling,or is it the amplitude or frequency of the movement of a single air particle,do we talk about its frequency and amplitude?

Comment: Have you asked your teacher to clarify this issue for you?  If not, that is probably the best thing to do, as the teacher will give an explanation that is within the context and difficulty level of what he or she is teaching you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give this one more try.

Sound is a wave: it's both particle velocity and pressure varying with both space and time.

"Particle" here are not actual air molecules but you can think of them as "small volumes of air that move together", but that's a technicality that's not super relevant to the discussion.

If we have a sound wave with a single frequency, we can say the following things:

1. At any point in space the pressure will increase and decrease with time (around the average air pressure)
2. At any point in space the position of the air particle will move back and forth with time (around the rest position)
3. Frequency is the number of repeats of this cycle per second. It's the same for the particle movement and the pressure increase/decrease
4. Amplitude is the maximum displacement, velocity, or pressure increase. The amplitudes of velocity and pressure are different but (mostly) proportional.
5. The pattern repeats not only in time but also in space. The distance between two repetitions is the wavelength. The product of wavelength and frequency is the speed of sound. In air, a wave with a frequency of 1kHz has a wavelength of about 34cm. That's the spacing between, for example, two pressure peaks.

All of this is difficult to draw because there are more variables involved than you can display easily in a 2-dimensional drawing. That's why most drawings are simplifications and the appearance depends on the specific simplifications made.

Perception of sound is another topic. The relationship between physical sound and what happens in the human brain is VERY complicated. Roughly speaking, frequency is related to pitch and amplitude is (loosely) related to loudness but it's way more convoluted than this.

Answer (score 3):

Careful here because compressions and rarefactions ideally refer to the medium (collective oscillations) and not to the vibration of one individual air molecule. The motion of one molecule is pretty much random, and so what is states in the above graph about *motion of a single air molecule* is there probably for teaching purposes and not to be taken too literally.

But to answer the rest of your question, the amplitude is the maximum value of the displacement of the particles. So you can see the amplitude by looking at the value of $x$ at the points $t=(0.5,1.5,2.5,\ldots )\ ms$. At each of these points is a compression (or rarefaction) and following/adjacent points is the rarefaction (or compression).

You can’t actually “see” the frequency $f$, but you can see the period $T$, and then find the frequency through relation $$f=\frac 1T$$

Here we can see that it takes $2\ ms$ for the wave to complete one cycle, which is the period, or it completes one compression *and* one rarefaction in this time. So frequency $$f=\frac 12 =0.5\ ms^{-1}$$

Note that one compression *and* rarefaction occurs in one period, so this happens in $2\ ms$ or with frequency $0.5\ ms^{-1}$

> are these graphs incorrect?if yes,then what is frequency or amplitude,if not,then tell me one thing,we say that loudness or pitch of a sound is determined by its amplitude or frequency

No, they are not incorrect. Amplitude correlates with "loudness" while frequency correlates with pitch.

> loudness or pitch of a sound is determined by its amplitude or frequency,so,here,what frequency or amplitude are we talking about?

“Loudness” is the amplitude, and see above.

> frequency or amplitude of the pressure-position graph,that is, frequency or amplitude of compression or rarefaction travelling

Yes it is and see above.

> or is it the amplitude or frequency of the movement of a single air particle

Nope. Not for a *single* molecule as explained in my first paragraph. The *one single air molecule vibrating* is essentially and ideal way to explain the *collective motion* of the air molecules. Perhaps your teacher was trying to keep the explanation simple.

Comment: I didn't ask you to calculate what amplitude or frequency is in a wave graph,I asked u what do we mean in the case of sound when we speak of amplitude and frequency

Comment: And that is _exactly_ what I have done. What is it that you're not understanding?

Comment: So basically,the graph of vibration of a single air molecule is pretty random and will not yield anything useful,so,what we refer to as frequency and amplitude in our daily life is the frequency and amplitude of the pressure - position graph of the sound waves,which means amplitude is the amount of highest pressure of compression and lowest pressure of rarefaction,and frequency is the number of compression or rarefaction passing through a point within 1 second,right?

Answer (score 2):

The plot for a single air molecule is a misleading oversimplification.  Air molecules only change direction when they undergo a collision.  The average distance between collisions, the [mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path), depends on the pressure and density but for “air” is roughly $10^{-7}\,\mathrm m$.  The position of a single air molecule versus time will map out a [random walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) where the average distance between corners is about a hundred nanometers.  Your plot which shows continuous motion on a scale of $10^{-10}\,\mathrm m$, might possibly be appropriate for a sound wave in a *solid*, where $10^{-10}\,\mathrm m$ is a typical interatomic spacing.  But for air molecules, the scale is wrong.

I’ve never thought about the path of an individual air molecule moving as it participates in a sound wave. Perhaps I’ll do a calculation later.

You have a nice answer about how amplitude relates to loudness and frequency relates to pitch.  I have encountered non-musical students who don’t realize that “loudness” and “pitch” refer to different properties of a sound.  If you have access to a piano (or to an electronic piano-simulating app), the keys on the piano’s left side play low pitches a.k.a. low frequencies, while the keys on the right side play high pitches a.k.a. high frequencies.  You can play the low notes loudly or softly, and likewise you can play the high notes loudly or softly; the loudness is related to the amplitude.

Comment: So basically,the graph of vibration of a single air molecule is pretty random and will not yield anything useful,so,what we refer to as frequency and amplitude in our daily life is the frequency and amplitude of the pressure - position graph of the sound waves,which means amplitude is the amount of highest pressure of compression and lowest pressure of rarefaction,and frequency is the number of compression or rarefaction passing through a point within 1 second,right?

Comment: Yes, just like that.

Answer (score 1):

Both are different ways to think about the same sound wave. It is common to think of the amplitude of displacement of individual air particles in a sound wave when we are thinking about it abstractly, but measuring the amplitude of pressure differences tends to be more practical in real life.

Comment: So basically,the graph of vibration of a single air molecule is not commonly used,and when we refer to something about sound,what we mean as frequency and amplitude in our daily life is the frequency and amplitude of the pressure - position graph of the sound waves,which means amplitude is the amount of highest pressure of compression and lowest pressure of rarefaction,and frequency is the number of compression or rarefaction passing through a point within 1 second,right?